# Reasons for running .jar app as a daemon on linux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, jar, daemon

Bit of a basic question but I cant seem to find a straight answer

I have a java app that I currently run by issuing java -jar myapp.jar, but I am wondering what the advantages are to having it run as a daemon, I can run the jar on startup using a shell script so are there any other reasons from a performance / reliability point of view?? Or other issues that I have completely missed?

(running ubuntu 10.10)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are thinking of something like [Apache Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/index.html), then you would gain things like

- creation of pid file
- automatic restart if JVM crashes
- shutdown notification when OS is going down
- stop the process with a command
- run as root or downgraded user
- ...